# Error - Channel does not exist thrown while calling the approveformyorg function

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Configured a three node and two channel fabric network using 2.1 binaries and test-network in a multihost RAFT setup on cloud. Peers, Orderers, Channels including the Chaincode got created successfully. `QueryInstalled` retrieves the package id successfully as per [`DeployCC.sh`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh), but the approval process from Org1 throws the following error - `Error: failed to send transaction: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist`. DeployCC is invoked from Org1 and the similar error is thrown on Orderer log.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you certain the channels were created successfully? I would try listing the channels the peer has joined, try `peer channel list`, I expect you'll find something went wrong and the channel doesn't actually exist /  wasn't joined.

Comment: Yes, when I run peer channel list on each of the node, I get the correct list of channels to which the peer is connected to.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information provided, that `peer channel list` appropriately shows the channel as existing in the peer, but the orderer is reporting that the channel does not exist.

The only time a peer can be joined to a channel that the orderer does not know exists would occur when the peer was joined using a block for a channel on another ordering service.  Most often this can occur when scripts do not appropriately clean up artifacts from previous execution attempts.  Generally this can be because:

1. The old ledger for the peer still exists.  This could be because the local filesystem was not cleaned, or because docker persistent volumes were re-used. (You can look at your volumes via `docker volume list`).
2. The old block files (as retrieved via `peer channel create` or
   `peer channel fetch`) might have been left.  In this case, even if a
   new `peer channel create` failed, your script might still
   successfully join the peer to the old channel (which no longer
   exists).

I'd encourage you to do a thorough job removing all artifacts (ideally deleting everything, and then explicitly placing only the things you need).  I expect this will resolve your problem.

Edit: As Rob notes below, if you are using the sample scripts, `./network.sh down` should effectively clean your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jason's suggestion, you could try `./network.sh down` in your test-network directly, it does a pretty good job of deleting everything.

Then start again with

```
./network.sh up
./network.sh createChannnel
./network.sh deployCC
```